# Exact string matching and replacement of a file using PERL script

Tags: string, algorithm, perl, replace

I have two files like below.

1. Address File [Look up file]

> ```
> POST OFFICE,PO
> SUITE ACCESS ROOM, SAR
> SUITE,STE
> STREET,ST
> NEW YORK,NY
> POST,PST
> LONG LINE STREET,LLS
> ```

1. Main file [Where need to search and replace exact string]

> ```
> ARIJIT, 192 POST OFFICE, SUITE
> CHANDA, 13 HP STREET, NY
> RAM, POSTING POST, LONG LINE STREET
> ROY, POST 3009, SUITE ACCESS ROOM
> ```

Expected Output :

> ```
> ARIJIT, 192 PO, STE
> CHANDA, 13 HP ST, NEW YORK
> RAM, POSTING PST, LLS
> ROY, PST 3009, SAR
> ```

I am using below code but still not able to get any success. I am very new in PERL. The code is working fine for single WORD but not working for Multiple words.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open( my $out_fh, ">", "output.txt" ) || die "Can't open the output file for writing: $!";

open( my $address_fh, "<", "Address.txt" ) || die "Can't open the address file: $!";
my %lookup = map { chomp; split( /,/, $_, 2 ) } <$address_fh>;

open( my $file_fh, "<", $ARGV[0] ) || die "Can't open the file.txt file: $!";
while (<$file_fh>) {
    my @line = split;
    for my $char ( @line ) {
        ( exists $lookup{$char} ) ? print $out_fh "$lookup{$char} " : print $out_fh "$char ";
    }
    print $out_fh "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is at `my @line = split;`, which splits the line into *words*. As some of your replacements contain multiple words, you can't do that.

Instead, you should build a regex that matches all your keys, e.g:

```
my $keywords = join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %lookup;
my $keywords_rx = qr/\b$keywords\b/;
```

The `\b` assertion matches at word boundaries. We also have to sort the keys so that longer alternatives are tried *before* shorter matches. Otherwise, `SUITE ACCESS ROOM` may never be matched.

The substitution is then performed on a line like `s/($keywords_rx)/$lookup{$1}/g`.